# LINQ query to Group and SUM values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a SQL Query like this and I am trying to convert this to C# code using LINQ but I have no idea how to get the SUM & Average values using LINQ.

**SQL Query**

```
Select SID, SName, EID, SUM(CAST(EPoints AS Decimal(18, 2)))/COUNT(EFID), EFID,  
SUM(CASE WHEN FValue = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Y',  
SUM(CASE WHEN FValue = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'N'
from TestTable where ISNULL(FValue, '') != ''
Group By SID, SName, EID, EFID
Order By SID, SName, EID, EFID
```

Also, I have converted the above SQL query to Linq expression partially but got stuck in SUM & Average part so, can someone tell me how to do this?

```
var sortedTable = testTableData.AsEnumerable()
.Where(r => r.Field<string>("FValue") != "")
.GroupBy(r => new
 {
     SID = r.Field<int>("SID"),
     SName = r.Field<string>("SName"),
     EID = r.Field<int>("EID"),
     EFID = r.Field<int>("EFID")   
 })
.OrderBy(g => g.Key.SID)
.ThenBy(g => g.Key.SName)
.ThenBy(g => g.Key.EID)
.ThenBy(g => g.Key.EFID)                                        
.Select(g => new {
    SID = g.Key.SID,
    SName = g.Key.SName,
    EID = g.Key.EID,
    EFID = g.Key.EFID                                            
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now... Please see the below code which I have used:

```
var sortedTable = testTableData.AsEnumerable()
.Where(r => r.Field<string>("FValue") != "")
.GroupBy(r => new
 {
     SID = r.Field<int>("SID"),
     SName = r.Field<string>("SName"),
     EID = r.Field<int>("EID"),
     EFID = r.Field<int>("EFID")   
 })
.OrderBy(g => g.Key.SID)
.ThenBy(g => g.Key.SName)
.ThenBy(g => g.Key.EID)
.ThenBy(g => g.Key.EFID)
.Select(g => new {
                        SID = g.Key.SID,
                        SName = g.Key.SName,
                        EID = g.Key.EID,
                        EFID = g.Key.EFID,    
                        Avg = g.Average(x => decimal.Parse(x.Field<string>("EPoints"))),
                        YesCount = g.Sum(x => x.Field<string>("FValue") == "Y" ? 1 : 0),
                        NoCount = g.Sum(x => x.Field<string>("FValue") == "N" ? 1 : 0)
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your `.select` part, you can use the built-in linq aggregate functions Average and Sum to do your needed aggregations, am not sure if the below compiles, however it should logically serve your need:

```
   .Select(g => new {
                SID = g.Key.SID,
                SName = g.Key.SName,
                EID = g.Key.EID,
                EFID = g.Key.EFID,
                EpointsAverage = g.Average(x => x.EPoints),
                YSum = g.Sum(x => (x.FValue == 'Y' ? 1 : 0)),
                NSum = g.Sum(x => (x.FValue == 'N' ? 1 : 0))
            });
```

Let me know how it goes, and if there is any issue to update my answer accordingly

Comment: Sorry its not working... I am getting compilation error.

Comment: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'FValue' and no extension method 'FValue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: are you sure your field of summation is `FValue` or it is `EFValue`?

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use aggregate functions provided in Entity framework to get your Result as::

```
var sortedTable = testTableData.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(r => r.EFValue!=null && r.EFValue!= "")
                    .GroupBy(r => new
                     {
                         SID = r.SID,
                         SName = r.SName,
                         EID = r.EID,
                         EFID = r.EFID   
                     })
                    .OrderBy(g => g.Key.SID)
                    .ThenBy(g => g.Key.SName)
                    .ThenBy(g => g.Key.EID)
                    .ThenBy(g => g.Key.EFID)                                        

                    .Select(g => new {
                        SID = g.Key.SID,
                        SName = g.Key.SName,
                        EID = g.Key.EID,
                        EFID = g.Key.EFID,

                        Avg=g.Average(x=>x.EPoints),
                        Y=g.Where(x=>x.FValue=="Y").Sum(x=>x.FValue),
                        N=g.Where(x=>x.FValue=="N").Sum(x=>x.FValue)
                    });
```

Comment: Sorry its not working... I am getting compilation error.